# preg_match() find all values inside of table?

Tags: php, curl, preg-match

hey guys,
a curl function returns a string $widget that contains regular html -> two divs where the first div holds a table with various values inside of `<td>`'s.

i wonder what's the easiest and best way for me to extract only all the values inside of the `<td>`'s so i have blank values without the remaining html.

any idea what the pattern for the preg_match should look like?

thank you.

Comment: use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: **Don use regex to parse HTML**, use an [html dom parser instead](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're betting off using a DOM parser for that task:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>world</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div>
   Something irrelevant
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$tds = $xpath->query('//div/table/tr/td');
foreach ($tds as $cell) {
    echo "{$cell->textContent}\n";
}
```

Would output:

```
foo
bar
hello
world
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not a suitable solution. You're better off loading it up in a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use regexps to parse HTML. Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) and [XPath](http://php.net/domxpath) instead. Here's an example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//td');
$result = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $result[] = $node->nodeValue;
}
// $result holds the values of the tds
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have very limited, well-defined HTML can you expect to parse it with regular expressions. The [highest ranked SO answer of all time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) addresses this issue.

He comes ...