# How should I modify this php preg_match now that I added an extra div around the span tags?

Tags: php, preg-match

I used to apply this **php preg_match**:

```
<?php preg_match( '!<div class="thumblock ">(.*)</div>!si' , wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(0, false, "", 0, "", false) , $n );
$thumbs_number = strip_tags( $n[1] ); ?>
```

to extract the number (in this case *2*) between the `.rating-result` span tags (only):

```
<div class="thumblock">
    <span class="rating-result">2</span>

    <div class="ratingtext">
      <div id="gdsr_thumb_124_a_up" class="gdt-size-20 gdthumb gdup">
        <div class="gdt-starrating"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="gdsr_thumb_124_a_dw" class="gdt-size-20 gdthumb gddw">
        <div class="gdt-starrating"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="raterclear"></div>
  </div>
```

Now, I modified the output (I added an extra div which surrounds the `.rating-result` span tags):

```
 <div class="thumblock">
    <div id="gdsr_thumb_text_137_a" class="gdt-size-20 voted inactive gdthumbtext">
      <span class="rating-result">2</span>
    </div>

    <div class="ratingtext">
      <div id="gdsr_thumb_137_a_up" class="gdt-size-20 gdthumb gdup">
        <div class="gdt-starrating"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="gdsr_thumb_137_a_dw" class="gdt-size-20 gdthumb gddw">
        <div class="gdt-starrating"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="raterclear"></div>
  </div>
```

Doing `var_dump` to the first `$thumbs_number` outputs: `string(2) "+1"`

Doing `var_dump` to the second `$thumbs_number` outputs: `string(2) "+1"`

But the function where I use the variable `$thumbs_number` doesn't work any more (`get_rating_class();` is placed in a div's class to add a class according to the number of thumbs):

```
function get_rating_class($thumbs_number) {
    if ($thumbs_number < 0) return ' bad';
    if ($thumbs_number < 2) return ' average';
    if ($thumbs_number < 4) return ' good';
    return ' excellent';
}

function rating_class($thumbs_number) {
    echo get_rating_class($thumbs_number);
}
```

Which is absolutely the same, but it seems like
How should I modified the `preg_match` in order to make it extract that number as it did before?

Comment: Why don't you just add the span placeholder then, or look for that one directly? Also you realize that it would be simpler with e.g. `qp($html)->find(".thumblock .rating-result").text()` [(...)](http://querypath.org/) - though it's unclear which is the appropriate approach for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern:

```
'!<div class="thumblock ">(.*)</div>!si'
```

has a space after thumblock. Once I removed that, it worked ok for me. Note however that the (.*) part of the pattern may include extra divs other than the thumblock one, as it matches greedily. If you make it match non-greedily by changing it to (.*?), then it will only match to the first  it finds, which may not be the thumblock div.

These problems occur because of the limitations of using regular expressions - they're not designed to parse nested tags, such as html. The answer to this question might help:
[preg_match() find all values inside of table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946850/preg-match-find-all-values-inside-of-table)